# Camel setHeader newbie error

Tags: header, websocket, apache-camel

I would just know where I'm wrong with this route.
I'm trying to return a messsage via a web socket route, but I'm unable to set camel connection key:

```
from("jms:queue:subscriptionValidationError").log("Receiving error message: ${body} ${in.headers.websocket.connectionKey}")
    .setHeader(WebsocketConstants.CONNECTION_KEY, simple("${in.headers.websocket.connectionKey}"))
    .log("Sending error message: ${body} ${out.headers.websocket.connectionKey}")
    .to("websocket://0.0.0.0:9292/subscribeErrors?staticResources=classpath:webapp");
```

This gives me a log without the connection key on the second log operation:

```
 Receiving error message: doit suivre "[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+" 60f7cc44-9d9b-4bde-905a-d7d51be7661a 
 Sending error message: doit suivre "[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\@[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"
```

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your log() references the `out.header`...but setHeader() is setting the `in.header`

see http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: Ok, but I thought headers where copied from one message to an other. My function's signature is `@InOut public String subscriptionValidationErro(String in){...}`